# Stereo audio Arduino MKR Zero

Tags: audio

I am doing a project in which I need to have a stereo audio output in Arduino MKR Zero. The quality of the audio is not important: 8 bit, 44 kHz would be enough. Is it possible to use two combined PWM outputs to do that, maybe with the library TMRpcm (is it supported by MKR?)? Or is it a better solution to interface it with a I2S stereo DAC?

Thank you
Alessandro